# File lines not being replaced, even though I coded it to do so?

Tags: c#, .net

I'm trying to run through each line in a file which is a link. I then add to a string list all the dead links (links that return 404 or have a specific phrase printed on the page. It all works okay so far, but the only problem I currently face is it doesn't remove them from the file as I request near the end.

Why is this?

```
using System.Collections.Generic;

namespace dead_link_finder
{
    using System;
    using System.IO;
    using System.Net;
    using System.Threading;

    static class Program
    {
        private static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Console.ForegroundColor = ConsoleColor.White;

            var fileToScan = Console.ReadLine();
            var reader = new StreamReader(fileToScan);
            string line;
            var deadLinks = new List<string>();

            while ((line = reader.ReadLine()) != null)
            {
                Log("Scanning: " + line, ConsoleColor.White);

                using (var webClient = new WebClient())
                {
                    try
                    {
                        var content = webClient.DownloadString(line);

                        if (content.Contains("text-danger"))
                        {
                            deadLinks.Add(line);
                        }
                    }
                    catch (WebException wex)
                    {
                        if (((HttpWebResponse)wex.Response).StatusCode == HttpStatusCode.NotFound)
                        {
                            deadLinks.Add(line);
                        }
                    }
                }
            }

            reader.Close();

            Console.WriteLine();
            Console.WriteLine("Found: " + deadLinks.Count + " dead links in the collection.");
            Console.WriteLine();

            Thread.Sleep(5000);

            Console.WriteLine("Removing the dead links, please wait...");

            foreach (var deadLink in deadLinks)
            {
                var str = File.ReadAllText(fileToScan);
                File.WriteAllText(fileToScan, str.Replace(deadLink, ""));
            }

            Console.WriteLine();
            Console.WriteLine("Finished...");

            Console.ReadKey(true);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Ewww you're reading and writing the exact same file many times inside a loop.  Don't do that, instead read it once, loop replacing each link (working in memory only), then write all the changes.

Comment: Thanks, I didn't notice this. Why are people downvoting, it would be nice if you could leave a comment to why you're downvoting the question.

Comment: I would be a better question if you told us whether the `deadlinks` collection actually contains elements.. Also: Never ask here before making use of the debugger, your best friend and always report the findings..

Answer (score 0):

You can try this. Parse the file contents into a list, save the dead links in another and then use the LINQ extension method `Except()` to get the difference.

This code is a bit messy and tries to do alot of things in one go. You should probably split it up into more manageable pieces like `ReadFile()`, `CheckLinks()` and `WriteFile()` or something.

```
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System;
using System.IO;
using System.Net;
using System.Threading;
using System.Linq;

namespace dead_link_finder
{
    static class Program
    {
        private static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Console.ForegroundColor = ConsoleColor.White;

            var fileToScan = Console.ReadLine();
            var links = File.ReadAllLines(fileToScan);
            var deadLinks = new List<string>();
            var webClient = new WebClient();

            foreach (var link in links)
            {
                try
                {
                    var content = webClient.DownloadString(link);

                    if (content.Contains("text-danger"))
                    {
                        deadLinks.Add(link);
                    }
                }
                catch (WebException wex)
                {
                    if (wex.Status == WebExceptionStatus.NameResolutionFailure )
                    {
                        deadLinks.Add(link);
                    }
                }
            }

            Console.WriteLine();
            Console.WriteLine("Found: " + deadLinks.Count + " dead links in the collection.");
            Console.WriteLine();

            Thread.Sleep(5000);

            Console.WriteLine("Removing the dead links, please wait...");

            var justTheGoodLinks = links.Except(deadLinks);
            File.WriteAllLines(fileToScan, justTheGoodLinks);

            Console.WriteLine();
            Console.WriteLine("Finished...");

            Console.ReadKey(true);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: upvote for `Except` downvote for not adressing the actual problem. Which imo doesn't exist at all - ((Except, of course the mistake of rereading and rewriting the whole file for each of its lines..))